# is there a Way to Grab the Filename and location from a File that is being downloaded by selenium and webdriver

Tags: selenium, download

I have a script that automates downloading a file using selenium and webdriver as chrome
basically, it logs in to a work website, and clicks on some settings to prepare to download a report file, and then clicks the download button

Is there a way for selenium or any other library to grab the file location and name of that file that is downloading or has just downloaded so I can store it in a variable to use later in the script

I do not know if the relative path will work or if it needs to be a full windows path name for it to work... probably safe to assume full path is more guaranteed to work

example being C:\Users\FunnyUserName\Downloads\report.xls

Adding Code to show what is happening better

```
#For Report Pull
#-----------------------------------------------
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import datetime

import os
import glob






###############################################################
#Pull Report                                                  #
###############################################################




#Open Web Driver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()


#Open Website and Log in
print('Open Website and Log In')
browser.get(('https://SomeWebsite.com'))


print('Working on Getting the QC Report')
print('Please Stand By')

#####
#I Removed a lot of stuff not necessary to this question



#Get the File
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="btnGenerateReport"]'))).click()


time.sleep(4)



#Working on getting the last downloaded Filename
# get the user download folder (dynamic so will work on any machine)
downLoadFolder =os.path.join( os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), 'Downloads')




print(downLoadFolder)
#This shows the correct folder....
#In My Case C:\Users\My UserName\Downloads



# get the list of files
list_of_files = glob.glob(downLoadFolder+"/*.*") # * means all if need specific formats (if you are looking for any specific format then specify eg: "/*.xls" to filter)


print (list_of_files)
#Always Shows ['C:\\Users\\My UserName\\Downloads\\desktop.ini']





# get the latest file name
#Forced the Folder and file type as a test
latest_file = max(glob.glob("C:/Users/My Username/Downloads/*.xls"), key=os.path.getctime)
#print the latest file name

print(latest_file)
#Returns:latest_file = max(glob.glob("C:/Users/My Username/Downloads/*.xls"), key=os.path.getctime)
#ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: You should be able to define the `"download.default_directory":downloadPath` in chrome options. And use the filesystem to get the latest file downloaded and change the name using the same.

Comment: thats not an option
the script will be run by many many people
and I cant force them all to change their download directorys

Comment: Check my answer and let me know, how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in the python.

Imports Needed:

```
import glob
import os
```

Script:

```
# get the user download folder (dynamic so will work on any machine)
downLoadFolder =os.path.join( os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), 'Downloads')
# get the list of files
list_of_files = glob.glob(downLoadFolder+"/*") # * means all if need specific formats (if you are looking for any specific format then specify eg: "/*.xlsx" to filter)
# get the latest file name
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
#print the latest file name
print(latest_file)
```

Comment: this always returns that C:\Users\My Username\Downloads\desktop.ini is the latest file....

Comment: what's the latest file that you downloaded?

Comment: In this case... its `C:\Users\My Username\Downloads\QCEquipmentSchedulingReportExport.xls`
thru Chrome being operated by WebDriver in Selenium

Comment: If I force it to `max(glob.glob("C:/Users/My Username/Downloads/*.xls"), key=os.path.getctime)`
I get `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: Do you have `.xls' or '.xlsx' files in downloads?

Answer (score 0):

I might have figured out where the problem is

I need it to grab the actual downloads directory, not the system default

I'm testing on my home computer, it default downloads to my dropbox download directory that I share with my work computer as well

so its not C:\Users\My Username\Downloads\

its actually D:\Dropbox\Downloads... which is where my chrome default is set currently

how do I get the chrome download directory?